# CaseInsensitiveMap.convertKey

Tags: java, dictionary, character

Why `org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap.convertKey()` method uses `Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]))`?

`Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]))` and `Character.toLowerCase(chars[i])` are the same logic?

```
protected Object convertKey(Object key) {
    if (key != null) {
        char[] chars = key.toString().toCharArray();
        for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]));
        }
        return new String(chars);
    } else {
        return AbstractHashedMap.NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This interested me, so I created a loop to check if there are any character that needs this extra step. And I'm surprised to see that there are quite a few letters which doesn't reach the same letter with using only toUpper, comparred to toLower then toUpper. The following snippet produces letters which reaches different letters:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        val atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
        IntStream.generate(atomicInteger::getAndIncrement)
                .limit(Character.MAX_VALUE)
                .forEach(i -> {
                    char c = (char) i;
                    if (Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(c)) != Character.toLowerCase(c)) {
                        System.out.printf(
                                "%s is not equal to %s%n",
                                Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(c)),
                                Character.toLowerCase(c)
                        );
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

For example:

```
μ is not equal to µ
i is not equal to ı
s is not equal to ſ
ι is not equal to ͅ
...
```